# lucidworks solr installation

Tags: installation, solr

Do you know how to install Lucidworks Solr without windowing system / gui?

thanks
Joyce

Answer (score 2, accepted):

java -jar LucidWorks.jar -console

Comment: If you need to reinstall it in a different location then you did the first time, make sure to look in your home directory for a .lucid (?) directory that stores install preferences!

Comment: Can you help me by providing a link to a page that describes how the install preferences should go into the .lucid directory?  Thank you kindly, Joyce